# io_service hangs on destruction

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I use `boost::asio::io_service` to process work in `Foo`. Now this works fine until I it exits out of `~Foo` and hangs somewhere in `io_service` destructor (in destructor of service_registry).
Am I doing something wrong?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void bar();
    boost::asio::io_service _ioService;
    unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> _ioWork;
    thread _thread;
};

Foo::Foo() :
    _ioWork( new boost::asio::io_service::work(_ioService) ),
    _thread([&]() {
        _ioService.run();
    }) {
}

Foo::~Foo() {
    _ioWork.release();
    _ioService.stop();
    _thread.join();
    // works great till here
}

void
Foo::bar() {
    auto writer = []()
    {
        // Some magic code
    };

    _ioService.post( writer );
}
```

I kind of wonder, why `_thread` will not join, when I do not call `stop` on `_ioService`.

Comment: Attach your debugger and find out what's blocking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `_ioWork.release()` (or after calling `release`, delete the pointer you get).

Here's what the documentation says about `release`:

> Releases the ownership of the managed object if any. get() returns nullptr after the call.

In your code, your `_ioWork` object gets leaked; it is probably what is making your `ioService` hang.

Comment: That is AFAIU the prefered way of keeping the service running.

Comment: But your problem is that the service won't stop running. You're keeping it running by not deleting the io_service::work object.